# javascript code returned from ad server

Tags: javascript, security, intranet

We are trying to implement ads on our website. We send a javascript call to the ad server which in turn returns javascript as response.

The returned javascript is in as follows:

`document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/;net=wfm;u=,wfm-21344506162_1343958067,1290bc3a7d845dc,health,ax.10-wfm.hliv_l-wfm.health_l-bv.am-bv.ax-bv.b77-bv.b21-bv.b26-bv.c18-bv.b76-bv.c44-bv.b7-bv.b48-bv.c22-bv.c4-bv.b79-bv.c9-bv.c17-bv.c39-bv.c12-bv.c3-bv.b13-bv.a65;pos=top;ugc=0;!c=aaa;tile=1;sz=300x250;cmw=owl;contx=health;cmd=www.abc.com;an=10;bu=109;br=390;btg=wfm.hliv_l;btg=wfm.health_l;btg=bv.am;btg=bv.ax;btg=bv.b77;btg=bv.b21;btg=bv.b26;btg=bv.c18;btg=bv.b76;btg=bv.c44;btg=bv.b7;btg=bv.b48;btg=bv.c22;btg=bv.c4;btg=bv.b79;btg=bv.c9;btg=bv.c17;btg=bv.c39;btg=bv.c12;btg=bv.c3;btg=bv.b13;btg=bv.a65;ord=114194322"></scr'+'ipt>');`

The issue is happening when viewing the website within the company vs outside the company. For the same javascript within  companys network throws the following error

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html

When viewed outside company's network, the ad displays fine.

Any insights on why this could be happening

Comment: Check the headers the response are being transmitted with.

Comment: The error seems pretty descriptive. You should emit `Content-type: text/javascript`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The response is returned from some external vendor on which I do not have control. can I just set the content type in my page?

Comment: Is it `<script src="http://theadserver.com/myad.js"></script>`? Or is it an `iframe`? How is it being included? If it's Ajax, you can't get Javascript and run it (without JSONP or CORS, which aren't really relevant here) without `eval()`ing, which you *should not do*.

Comment: its not iframe. just the code I have pasted above. and strangely the file which contains the above code does not end in .js.

Comment: How do you get the code itself? Are you calling it with `<script src="...">`? Are you copying and pasting it into a file yourself? And if the file is served with a `Content-type: text/javascript`, it's file URL reference could be `http://what.who/monkey.christmas` and still run in a `script` include.

Comment: no. we send out javascript code with the ad server URL, and the server responds with the above pasted code. If you check the code above, it has some more links which contains similar javascript. the fact that it works when viewed from home is driving me crazy in fixing the issue when its not working internally

Comment: Post all of your markup. You're not understanding what I'm asking.

Comment: yes, your right, the file URL reference is what you have posted. I cant post the entire markup here...sorry about that

Comment: I think you need to contact the ad service's tech support. You might try putting `<script type="text/javascript" src=...`, but I'm not sure that will work if the source type is incorrect.

Comment: Push comes to shove, you could [parse out the `src` attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/WxRTD/) from the response. I'd ask them what you should be doing different, though.

Comment: ok, thanks Jared. I will try some of your suggestions and post back here